# How do I add text to filename when uploading to server in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to add some text before a file name that I'm uploading to my website (server), for example this is how i upload a file to my website via PHP

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

This works fine, but what if i wanted to add for example, "TEST" in front of the file name when it is uploaded to my server (website)

(I've tried the following with no success)

```
move_uploaded_file('TEST'.$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

I've researched all around for an answer but haven't been been able to find one for almost two weeks now, hopefully my question is clear enough for you to understand.. Any ways, thanks for reading!

Comment: But... how you set the value of `$uploadfile`? Set its value prepending 'TEST'. Otherwise: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'TEST'.$uploadfile);`

Comment: @fusion3k i feel like an idiot... It was soo simple... Lol anyways Thank you for the help !!

Comment: Hate is not common for StackOverflow or it will be moderated out, don't worry :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = 'TEST' . $temp;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $newfilename);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works perfect

Comment: Welcome @Cod1ng, Please accept this answer so anyone can use this.

Comment: I was going to, but it said i couldn't accept the answer for up to 30 mins (when i first posted this) so i forgot about it. It's actually a really STUPID feature StackOverflow has implemented.